# How to remove the duplicate values in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```js
<script>
    $("#filter").on("shown.bs.popover",function(){
        $(".popover-content input[type=checkbox]").on("click",function(){
            if(this.checked)
   {
                this.setAttribute("checked","checked");
            }
   else
   {
                this.removeAttribute("checked");
            }
            $("#customdiv").html($(".popover-content").html());
        });
    }); 
 
 function fieldsFilter(flag,value,chkClass)
 { 
  var checkedfields = new Array();
  
  $('.'+chkClass).each(function() 
  {    
   if($(this).is(':checked'))
   {
    checkedfields.push($(this).val()); 
    document.getElementById('scatFilters').value;
    document.getElementById('ssrcFilters').value;
   }
   else
   { 
    document.getElementById('scatfFilters').value='';
    document.getElementById('ssrcfFilters').value = '';
   }
  }); 
  $('#'+flag+'Filters').val(checkedfields);
 }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="content" class="content">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="email-btn-row hidden-xs inbox-actions" id="inbox-actions">
   <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id='filter'><i class="fa fa-filter"></i></a>
   <div class='hide' id='customdiv'>
    <div class="panel-group">
     <button href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" onclick="clearFilter()">Clear Filter</button>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
         <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
         Representatives
        </a>
       </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <?php 
         foreach($rep_options as $rep_id => $rep_name){?>
         <input type="checkbox" class="RepClicked" name="rep_<?=$rep_id?>" id="rep_<?=$rep_id?>" onchange="fieldsFilter('rps',this.value,'RepClicked');" value="<?=$rep_id?>" <? if(in_array($rep_id,$rep_name)) { echo "checked"; } ?>/>
         <span style="font-size:12px;"><?=$rep_name?></span>
         <br/>
        <?php }?>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse2">
         <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
         Status
        </a>
       </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
       <div class="panel-body">
        <?php 
         foreach($status_options as $status_id => $status){?>
         <input type="checkbox" class="StatusClicked" name="status_<?=$status_id?>" id="status_<?=$status_id?>" onchange="fieldsFilter('sts',this.value,'StatusClicked');" value="<?=$status_id?>" <? if(in_array($status_id,$status)) { echo "checked"; } ?>/>
         <span style="font-size:12px;"><?=$status?></span>
         <br/>
        <?php }?>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="email-btn-row hidden-xs inbox-actions" id="inbox-actions" style="float:right">
   <form id="allFilters" name="" class="" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>missed_call_campaign/export">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="rpsFilters" class='hiddenFld' id="rpsFilters" value="<?=implode(',',$rep_id);?>" placeholder="rps"/>
      <input type="text" name="stsFilters" class='hiddenFld' id="stsFilters" value="<?=implode(',',$status_id);?>" placeholder="sts"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If i check the checkbox in popover, the text box will hold the values double times, actually what i want is the textbox should taken the value single time. The above jquery script is used for hold the checked checkbox value when i close the popover. Because of the first jquery script, the value in the textbox is taken double times. sorry for my english. can any one please help me out of this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAWFW.png)

Comment: Any one please give me some reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your checkedfields.push($(this).val()) line inside a condition
like

```
if(checkedfields.indexOf($(this).val())==-1){
                    checkedfields.push($(this).val());                  
                }
```

Comment: Thanku so much for your reply sir. Now it's working fine.